# Convolution: $ f (-)*g = g(-)* f$ does this mean both $f$ and $g$ have to be even functions?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, convolution, signal-processing

Assuming $f$ and $g$ are different functions, does $ f (-)*g = g(-)* f$ mean both $f$ and $g$ have to be even functions? 
In fact, this is equivalent to $f\star g = g \star f$ (i.e., cross-correlation of $f$ on $g$ equals to cross-correlation of $g$ on $f$). However, cross-correlation is in general non-commutative. So my guess is that for this equality to be hold, both $f$ and $g$ have to be even function. Is this right? What will be the formal proof for this? Any suggestions? Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Why does it have to be equivalent to $f\ast g=g\ast f$? You just cannot simply assume they are even right?

Comment: Hi Troy, $f*g$ is convolution and $f \star g$ is cross-correlation. Cross-correlation is in general not commutative which means $f\star g\neq g\star f$. The following is always true: $f \star g = f(-)\star g$

Comment: I mean $f*g = f(-)\star g$ is true

Comment: Sorry about that ;-).

Answer (score 1):

For real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ a simple inspection of the definition shows that $(f\star g)(x)=(g\star f)(-x)$, so if we impose commutativity we get that $f\star g$ must be an even function. This is the case for instance when one of the two functions is odd and the other is even, for if say $f$ is even and $g$ is odd then:

\begin{aligned}
(f\star g)(x)\; & = \int f(u)g(u-x)\mathrm{d}u\\
& = \int f(-u) g(-u+x)\mathrm{d}(-u)\\
& = (f\star g)(-x)\;.
\end{aligned}

Notice that if both $f$ and $g$ are even then $f\star g$ is even:

\begin{aligned}
(f\star g)(x)\; & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u)g(x-u)\mathrm{d}u\\
\text{Let }t=-u.\text{ Then }\mathrm{d}t=-\mathrm{d}u\\
& = -\int_\infty^{-\infty} f(-t) g(x+t)\mathrm{d}(t)\\
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) g(-x-t)\mathrm{d}t\\
& = (f\star g)(-x)\;.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Hi johndoe, thanks for your answer. From $f \star g$, how did you get the conclusion that one of $f$ and $g$ has to be even and the other must be odd? In addition, if both $f$ and $g$ are even, then the mirror reflection of $f$ is $f$, $f\star g = f*g$ which is even.

Comment: I've added more details, hope I didn't miscalculated though!

Comment: Hi johndoe, I don't see how $f\star g$ could be odd. An easy counterexample could be $f$ and $g$ are gaussian distribution with different variance. $f\star g$ would also be gaussian which is positive on $R$(which is even). In fact, I just realised that even if $f$ and $g$ are both not even, the result of their cross-correlation still could be even. So my intuition is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry for the mess. I think we should first agree on the definitions of convolution and cross-correlation. What's yours?

Comment: Hi johndoe, consider $f$ and $g$ are both positive and even (e.g. Gaussian distribution). Convolution or cross correlation of two positive even function will not give you negative value.

Comment: I understand there is something wrong here. Would you please add your definitions of convolution and cross-correlation into the main body of your question? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17177/discussion-between-aniki-aishiteru-and-johndoe).